# How to determine winding type of a generator?

Tags: generator

I recently asked a question about a component from a wind generator (see [my original question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/662733/what-are-these-components-for/662734#662734)).

When looking through the answers, it occurred to me that I really didn't fully understand how the stator was wired.  I had just 'assumed' that the 3 phases were on the White, Green and Yellow wires, and were all relative to the Black wire.  And that was the assumption I was going to use when connecting them to the 3-phase bridge rectifier.  However, mention was made of Y topology and 'wye' topology (probably the same?) but it would be good to get some feedback on

- what topology my generator winding conforms to?
- is my intended connection to the rectifier correct/valid?

What I have done is measure the resistance across all possible pairs, and tabulated below.
[image: Winding resistances]

Would appreciate someone clarifying the 2 questions above.

Cheers,
Mike

Following up on comment below

> There's something weird there. You can't have ye-wh = 4.1 ohms and ye-gn-wh = 0.5 + 5.0 = 5.5 ohms. Make sure you're not measuring the resistance of the thermal cutouts. –
> Transistor
> 19 hours ago

My measurements did indeed include the thermal cutoff resistance, however, this is only 0.2Ohms on one, and not measurable on the other.  However, have now retabulated the results excluding the thermal cutoffs and they're very similar to my original readings.

[image: Measurements without thermal cutoff resistance]

I've ordered a 3-phase bridge rectifier (SBR2056) - pinout diagram below.
I'd appreciate advice on how to connect the stator wires to the rectifier.
I'm assuming that the White/Yellow/Green wires are each connected to a separate phase coil, so I would connect these to pins 2, 3 and 4.
The DC output would be +ve on pin 1 and -ve on pin 5.  So where should I connect the black stator wire to?  I'm assuming it would also be connected to pin 5.  Is this correct?

I've just found this link [Wiring 3-phase bridge rectifier](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/286302/how-to-wire-a-three-phase-bridge-rectifier) to an article suggesting the neutral can be left unconnected.

[image: SBR2056 pinout]

Thanks for any help,
Mike

Comment: There's something weird there. You can't have ye-wh = 4.1 ohms and ye-gn-wh = 0.5 + 5.0 = 5.5 ohms. Make sure you're not measuring the resistance of the thermal cutouts.